# Seems the indexes are missing for new entities created since some time late June 1st, 2015

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have an app running on google appengine and it works well until some time today (June 1st, 2015). We found that new entities created are missing index and they are not in the query result. I'm not sure what happens, since old entities don't have this problem. The single field index seems working fine. I don't have any clue how to solve this issue. I appreciate if anyone can shed some light on it.

Here is one example:

We have an entity like this:

```
EntityA {
  String A;
  String B;
  Integer C;
}
```

We have such records in datastore:

```
A   B   C
123 bb  1  - old record
123 bb  2  - old record
123 bb  3  - new record
```

There are index for [A, B], [A, C], [A, B, C]

We found that following GQL

```
Select * from EntityA where A='123' and B='bb';
```

Will get result like this, where the new record is missing:

```
A   B   C
123 bb  1
123 bb  2
```

The new record is missing. However if we query with single field index like this:

```
Select * from EntityA where A='123';
```

Or like this:

```
Select * from EntityA where B='bb';
```

We see the new record in result.

```
A   B   C
123 bb  1
123 bb  2
123 bb  3
```

Also, query like this will get empty result:

```
Select * from EntityA where C=3;
```

But query on first two records return proper result:

```
Select * from EntityA where C=1;
Select * from EntityA where C=2;
```

So I feel like the indexes are not created for the new records.

Comment: Are there any clues in the console (Storage > Cloud Datastore > Indexes)?

Comment: @tx802 thx, there is no clue in the console. But the issue is gone now, I see new records in query results. However I still have to manually save all the records which were created during this period to re-create the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is changed from my side, but the issue seems to be gone now earlier at June 2nd, and I do see new records in query results. Sill no clue what's the cause, and not sure if any other one see the same issue as mine. I still have to manually save all the records which were created during this period to re-create the indexes.

Comment: [This](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15015) may be relevant.

Comment: @tx802 beat me by 20 minutes :P. Yes, I do believe it is a relevant link and you were possibly affected by this.

Comment: @tx802 thank you again, I feel so "LUCKY" that I'm chosen to be the one of that 0.01%, hope this would never happen again.

Comment: You can subscribe on `google-appengine-downtime-notify@googlegroups.com` to be notified about any accidents.